# Directive inside a ng-repeat not working only first one seen

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have written code like below

```
 <div  ng-repeat="race in Races" ng-if="$index == selectedRace">
<div id="weeksOut" racedetails="race" raceday-donut></div>
</div>
```

And my directive looks like below

```
   .directive('racedayDonut', function(Donut){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        transclude: true,
        scope : {
                    racedetails         : '='
                },
        replace : true,
        template : "<div></div>",
        link: function(scope)
        {
             scope.$watch('racedetails',function(newData)
            {
                var tempRaceDetails         =  newData;

                if(tempRaceDetails)
                {
                    Donut.drawDonutSvc(tempRaceDetails.weeks, tempRaceDetails.Perc, 90,'#FEFEFE', '#5b5b5b',' WEEKS OUT', 'weeksOut');
                }               
            });
        }
      };

    })
```

Only first directive gets drawn, but second and others are not show. when selected index changes and data changes, it comes inside but not drawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the problem is your are having `id="weeksOut"` inside `ng-repeat` which is repeating number of times, And its not a good practice to have same id `selector` multiple times on the same page. When you make query for that selector `jQuery`/`DOM` will gets confused, I might return first object.

If you really want to make your directive to make selector specific then I'd suggest generate your `selector` value dynamically by adding unique value with combination of `weeksOut-`, like `tempRaceDetails` has some `id` which tells the uniqueness of that record. So simply it would look like `weeksOut-{{tempRaceDetails.id}}`

**Markup**

```
<div  ng-repeat="race in Races" ng-if="$index == selectedRace">
   <div id="weeksOut-{{racedetails.id}}" racedetails="race" raceday-donut></div>
</div>
```

And in your directive you could use that `id` attribute

```
Donut.drawDonutSvc(tempRaceDetails.weeks, 
     tempRaceDetails.Perc, 
     90,
     '#FEFEFE', 
     '#5b5b5b',
     'WEEKS OUT', 
     'weeksOut-'+ tempRaceDetails.id //passed DOM selector name.
);
```

Comment: I had tried this before, but was not working. Now it worked :)

Comment: @Hacker Glad to help you..Thanks :)